# Matplotlib plotting with float values for x

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, floating-point

I have tried to find the answer to this question, maybe its very easy and thats why i cant.

If I have made a Gaussian function and I want to plot it with Matplotlib.pyplot.plot, how can i do that with float values. I.e. values from -20<=x<=20 in increments of 0.1

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from math import exp
import numpy

#Parameters for the Gaussian 
A=1
c=10
t=0
a=1
x=[]

p=-20.
while p<=20:
    x.append(p)
    p+=0.1

def Gaussian(A,c,t,a,x):
    return A*exp(-((c*t-x)^2 /(4*a*c^2)))

plt.plot(x,Gaussian(A,c,t,a,x))
plt.show()
```

The Error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:--------/Gaussian Function.py", line 21, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,Gaussian(A,c,t,a,x))
  File "C:--------/Gaussian Function.py", line 19, in Gaussian
    return A*exp(-((c*t-x)^2 /(4*a*c^2)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with matplotlib.  You will get the same error if you just call `Gaussian(A, c, t, a, x)` without using matplotlib at all.  Your function accepts an argument `x` that is a list, and then tries to do stuff like `c*t-x`.  You can't subtract a list from a number.  As the error message suggests, you should probably make `x` a numpy array, which will allow you to do these kinds of vectorized operations on it.

Comment: They will also want to do `from numpy import exp` *instead* of `from math import exp`

Comment: Actually, you can pass also a single value for x. Then you have to handle single points from domain to get single values in the codomain.
So vectorizing makes sense (numpy) :)

Answer (score 2):

**There are some mistakes in your code. The corrected one is below:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Parameters for the Gaussian 
A, c, t, a = 1, 10, 0, 1
x = np.arange(-20,20,0.1)                       #use this instead

def Gaussian(A,c,t,a,x):
    return A*np.exp(-((c*t-x)**2/(4*a*c**2)))   #power in Python is ** not ^

plt.plot(x,Gaussian(A,c,t,a,x))
plt.show()
```

**and result is:**

[image]